# Can the Android app please give a more concise error when an image is too large to upload?

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app, images, uploader

The Android app simply reports something "went wrong" when trying to upload an image that is too large (>2 MB). I didn't realize there was anything wrong with my image until I happened to notice the 2 MB warning in the non-mobile site's image upload page.

A more concise "Image is too large" error would help users properly respond to the problem (and likely downsize their image, reupload, and continue).

#### Screenshots

The top right image selected:

> [image: Top right]

In progress...

> [image: "Uploading Image"]

The error:

> [image: "Sorry, something went wrong while trying to upload that image. Try again?"]

Also, the limit to file uploads is apparently 2MiB, not 2MB:
[image: screenshot of SE meta img uploader]

Comment: Can't reproduce. Uploaded 2.14Mb picture without any error. That's actually better than the web version which indeed won't allow to upload such images to begin with.

Comment: @Shadow: Try uploading a much larger image. OP: Please add the screenshot.

Comment: @Sonic oh. Well that crashed the app. There is a dupe, will find it later.

Comment: Regarding the edits from other users: I originally thought there was something wrong with my image, or with a proxy, or other service running on my device, etc. Hence the original "nothing wrong" vs. "anything wrong" ... "with my image." Also, I used "2Mb" instead of "2MB", since I believe the technical limit is 2 MiB; hence Shadow's inability to reproduce the error (2.14MB is still <2.0 MiB).

Comment: Whoops, typo in my last comment (but edit time is up); 2.14MB is *>* 2.0 MiB.

Comment: Still having the same issue. Image size errors just give a generic "something went wrong."