# Why are some images and GIF files hosted on i.stack.imgur.com larger than 2 MiB?

Tags: support, images, uploader, imgur

The upload limit for images and GIF files is [2 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179). However, some images and GIF files are larger than 2 MiB, e.g.:

- This [9.9 MiB GIF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mePaD.gif) posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53444289/395857).
- This [9.6 MiB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzltP.jpg) posted in this [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/121091/830).

Why are some images and GIF files hosted on i.stack.imgur.com larger than 2 MiB?

---

Notes:

- The Android app debuted in [2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/178179). The iPhone app debuted in [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220264/178179). However, this [2.2 MiB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIAD1.gif) posted in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5597/747) was uploaded in 2012.
- The chat uploader has a size limit of [4 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395765/178179) for JPG and PNG (I haven't looked at GIF) and large images are [lossily compressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333607/178179).

Comment: The size limit is not enforced in the chat uploader.

Comment: @Sonic first, the posts linked here aren't chat, and the author of the first did not have 20 rep when posting, so it can't be from chat. Second, the other question most likely means **posting** images in chat, i.e. oneboxing, not uploading via imgur.

Comment: @Sonic also, while the uploader itself doesn't indeed check or enforce the limit, imgur itself does and trying to upload the 9mb gif from the first example question [fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zNPJ.png). Something else is in play here. Please retract your close vote.

Comment: Might be that those two were uploaded via SE android app, as you can see in my comment to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305860/can-the-android-app-please-give-a-more-concise-error-when-an-image-is-too-large), I was able to upload images bigger than the limit using the app. Can't check now of course, but if you can find large images that were uploaded after the apps have been shut down, it will nullify this option as well.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The chat uploader has a size limit of [4 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395765/178179) for JPG and PNG (I haven't looked at GIF) and large images are lossily compressed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda [On which day did it become impossible to upload images via the SE phone app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395772/178179)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt well that might be "grace period" by imgur allowing images bit larger than the declared limit. If you can find 10mb images posted before 2013 it will prove it's not from the apps without any doubt.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda isn't the imgur limit strictly [2 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179)?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yeah but still, sometimes there's margin for error left on purpose, e.g. here in SE we can still post answers to closed questions up to three hours after closure, and it's not official feature.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda AFAIK that limit is strictly ATM. Idk about 10  years ago. Also I'm not aware of any images above 10 MiB on i.stack.imgur.com